# Add and remove component dynamically from mat-list in Angular 7

Tags: angular

In one of my Angular components I have a `mat-list` that I want to use to display a list of child components. I want to allow the user to be able to add a component to this list by clicking a button below the list, and to remove a component from the list by clicking a remove button **on**  the component itself.

For context, the child component being created/removed is a component that is involved with holding information about a range of IP addresses. It contains two inputs, one for the starting range and one for the ending range.

I have the add functionality working, but the way it is implemented doesn't seem correct. The way I have it at the moment is by holding an array of `IpRange` objects (simple object that contains two strings), then using `*ngFor` I generate a new component each time an object is added to this array. The component is generated via `@Input ipRange: IpRange` within the child component.

However when I instantiate these new components I am creating them by passing an empty object to the array, which doesn't feel right.

ParentTemplate

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <mat-list>
                    <app-add-ip-dialog *ngFor="let ipRange of ipRanges" [ipRange]="ipRange"></app-add-ip-dialog>
                </mat-list>
            </div>
        </div>
```

ParentComponent

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit{

  ipRanges: IpRange[];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ipRanges = [];
  }

  addIpRange(): void {
    this.ipRanges.push({startingRange: '', endingRange: ''});
    console.log(this.ipRanges);
  }
}
```

ChildComponent

```
export class AddIpDialogComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() ipRange: IpRange;

  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(this.ipRange.startingRange + ' : ' + this.ipRange.endingRange);
  }
}
```

IpRange interface

```
export interface IpRange {
    startingRange: string;
    endingRange: string;
}
```

What I want to be able to do is instantiate a new component each time the user clicks the add button, then each component is able to keep track of its `startingRange` and `endingRange` via two way binding.

Then when the user wants to remove one of these components they simply have to click the remove button on the component and it then removes it from the mat-list.

Answer (score 0):

do these have to be separate components? I recently did something very similar where you were able to list files for upload in a form and I built an add/delete input functionality into it that would create a new input for each file to upload, and when the data is posted It gets sent in an array. That route might be easier. let me know if that's a change you'd be willing to make and I can show you some code. I did it using [Angular material Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-2-generating-and-importing-a-new-form-control)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Service as a centralized data store to distribute the ipRanges data to your components:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class IpRangesService() {
 ipRanges: ipRange[];
 ngOnInit() {
    this.ipRanges = [];
  }

  addIpRange() {
    this.ipRanges.push({startingRange: '', endingRange: ''});
    console.log(this.ipRanges);
  }
  removeIpRange(index) {
    this.ipRanges.slice(index,1);
  }
  getIpRangeData() {
    return this.ipRanges
  }
}
```

Then distribute it to your parent component

In the parent ts file:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit{

  ipRanges: IpRange[];

  constructor(private ipRangeService : IpRangeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ipRanges = this.ipRangeService.getIpRangeData();
  }
}
```

In your parent HTML template, pass an index property to your child and it behave as an indentifier for your child components:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <mat-list>
            <app-add-ip-dialog 
                *ngFor="let ipRange of ipRanges, let i = index" 
                [ipRange]="ipRange"
                [id]="i"> 
            </app-add-ip-dialog>
        </mat-list>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you can use that index from your child component, delete itself using the method `removeIpRange()` provide by the above service:

```
export class AddIpDialogComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() ipRange: IpRange;
  @Input() id: number;
  constructor(private ipRangeService : IpRangeService){}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  //function that listen to the remove click event
  onRemoveButtonClicked() {
     this.ipRangeService.removeIpRange(id);
  }
}
```